# ¿Cómo modificar particiones en Sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla x, la cual contiene datos numéricos y un índice que la ordena con una columna tipo `int` la cual tienen este formato de fecha (año/mes/día)(20171201).

Mi partition function es la siguiente:

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [partition_PF](int) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (

20130101, 20130201, 20130301, 20130401, 20130501, 20130601,
 20130701, 20130801, 20130901, 20131001, 20131101, 20131201, 

 20140101, 20140201, 20140301, 20140401, 20140501, 20140601, 
 20140701, 20140801, 20140901, 20141001, 20141101, 20141201,

 20150101, 20150201, 20150301, 20150401, 20150501, 20150601, 
 20150701, 20150801, 20150901, 20151001, 20151101, 20151201,

 20160101, 20160201, 20160301, 20160401,20160501, 20160601,
 20160701, 20160801, 20160901, 20161001,20161101,20161201,

 20170101, 20170201, 20170301, 20170401, 20170501, 20170601,
 20170701, 20170801, 20170901, 20171001, 20171101)
GO
```

y mi partition scheme es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [partition_PF] AS PARTITION 
[GoldPointSalesDetails_PF] TO (
[20130101], [20130201], [20130301], [20130401], [20130501], [20130601], [20130701], [20130801], [20130901], [20131001], [20131101],[20131201],

[20140101], [20140201], [20140301], [20140401], [20140501], [20140601], [20140701], [20140801], [20140901], [20141001], [20141101], [20141201],

[20150101], [20150201], [20150301],[20150401], [20150501], [20150601], [20150701], [20150801], [20150901], [20151001], [20151101], [20151201],

[20160101], [20160201], [20160301],[20160401], [20160501], [20160601], [20160701], [20160801], [20160901], [20161001], [20161101], [20161201],

[20170101], [20170201], [20170301],[20170401], [20170501], [20170601], [20170701], [20170801], [20170901], [20171001], [20171101], [20171201])
GO
```

quiero agregarle mas files y filegroups a partir de `20180101` hasta `20191201`
y luego reubicar la data en sus respectivos files y filegroups. Esto es el inconveniente mas grande que tengo. Encontré un sp en está página: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/partition/144876/
pero no lo logro adaptarlo a mi caso.

Es recomendable modificar el function, scheme e index ó crear un index nuevo con su propio function y scheme? es una tabla con miles de registros